# Scope/Isolate/Prefix angular material scss styles

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

### Problem

I want to integrate angular material scss, but scope and isolate it to only apply its styles to my application. I need this, because my angular application will be embedded in a big monolith. Therefore, we need to prefix our applications scss and have it scoped as it could style other parts of the application. The problem is, that if somebody uses the same class names like angular material does, the styles will win by specificity and this is uncontrollable and will lead to bugs.

### Our Idea

The styles should be isolated/scoped to just be applied to our `<my-app></my-app>` tag by prefixing all selectors automatically.

Generated styles should look like this:

```
my-app .mat-button {}
```

### Current Attempt

Our current attempt is to include it where we need it. It looks like the following:

**styles.scss**

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

my-app {
  @include mat-core();
  @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber";
}
```

The Problem with this solution is, that the scoping is applied to some classes, but not to all.

### Demo/Showcase

I created a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cyttgp?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) as showcase.

You can see the problem in the in the following screenshot:

[image]

Is there another option to have angular material styles isolated/scoped?

Answer (score 0):

The styles applied are still within the project.. If you want some app-wide styles that should not be in the top-level `styles.scss`, put them in `app.component.scss` and make sure that all other components are children of app.component.ts. Angular scopes (s)css files to its related component by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For angular material it seems to not be like that. I just tried what you say in the stackblitz and even though the definitions are now in app.component.scss, the `.mat-button` class is not scoped at all. You can see it on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mjvn92?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Comment: If you remove the contents of app.component.scss you'll see that the style is still applied; this must be coming from the material-ui package's styles. I suspect that when you embed this project into another project that doesn't have material-ui installed, these styles won't be applied to the parent app.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Ok, so this is happening because the styles are added in a <style> tag in the <head>. Is there any possible solution to change this handling? Maybe with ViewEncapsulation?

Comment: You can try that yeah.`ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` might place the style tag somewhere else